# Hooking a TV up a computer using A/V cables?

Tags: tv, media

I'd like to connect my old desktop to my (even older) TV, but I'm not 100% positive how.

Can anyone point me towards some info on how to do this?

Comment: What outputs are on your desktop? What inputs are on your TV? If you can't name them, then post a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a [VGA connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector) on your computer and a [composite input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video)  on your TV, a simple converter cable (such as [this one at monoprice.com](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10401&cs_id=1040113&p_id=2509&seq=1&format=4#feedback)) will do the trick.

For newer computers with digital only video cards, a more expensive converter is necessary - see [this one at monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011407&p_id=4724&seq=1&format=2#description) as well.

JDB